# importing pysrt module into pyCharm

Tags: python, import, module, pip, pycharm

I'm using **PyCharm** on a mac, running El Capitan. My code is:

`import pysrt`

I get an error message in PyCharm 2016.1.2 saying that it can't find the module.

(Earlier) In the a Windows Environment, I was able to: pip install pysrt, and then invoke Visual Studio 2015.

How can I get PyCharm to **import pysrt**?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may install `pysrt` in:`Project Interpreter` settings:

click the `+` button and type `pysrt` to install it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Thanks Guoliang, that worked.The Project Interpreter setting in PyCharm 2016.1.2 was in: 

File->Import Settings->Project Interpreter